# Average of Count of Cells for Day of Week in MS Excel

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2011

I'm looking to do an average of rows per week day. And so far, I haven't been able to figure it out. I'm using **Excel 2011 for Mac**.

**Here's a sample screenshot:**

[image]

**Here's the screenshot of the pivottable:**

[image]

What I'm trying to answer is how many missed calls are averaging per day of week.

Comment: How exactly do you distinguish between this Monday and next Monday?

Comment: Good question @user2313067, I don't know :S

Comment: Is there a date, or a week number in your columns?

Comment: Oh, yes. The date all these events happened @user2313067? Yup, there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that the date is located in column D.

I can't seem to find a way to do it with a pivot table, but an array formula can do it.

Just enter `=SUM(($C$2:$C$14="Monday")*($A$2:$A$14="no answer")*1)/SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($D$2:$D$14;$D$2:$D$14)>0;($C$2:$C$14="Monday")*1))` as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) to get the average number of unanswered calls on Monday (credits to [chris neilsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7100786) for counting the number of distinct mondays). Of course, replace the 14 with the actual last line of your data.

You can replace monday with a cell reference to just have to copy the formula to other cells. Here is the formula I used in my table:

```
=SUM(($C$2:$C$14=$J2)*($A$2:$A$14=K$1)*1)/SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($D$2:$D$14;$D$2:$D$14)>0;($C$2:$C$14=$J2)*1))
```

[image: Sample table]

The downside is that you seem to have to give it the exact last line of your table, as frequency doesn't play well with empty cells. Maybe someone has an idea for that.

Comment: The whole thing broke down when I passed 2000 rows :S But I think we're on the right path here!! Thanks so much!  Going to keep playing around in between family this weekend..

I wonder if there's any other way of doing this.. surely someone else needed something like this? lol

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, make sure your **Call Count** data source is in *number* format -

[image]
[click for larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPJGd.png)

Pivot table settings-

[image]
[click for larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIIeT.png)

Comment: Hi @Raystafarian. What it's doing is summing the number of missed calls on the Day and then averaging all the calls (if I'm right? sorry, I'm still kind of a newb). For example, my intention would be to count the number of missed calls on this monday, next monday, and so on for a few weeks and then answer - "On Mondays, on average, there's about 5.5 missed calls". Hope I'm making sense?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is doing.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be working for me: http://s4.postimg.org/5ptqbqhwt/image.png